# failed to build hello world application in android ndk using cygwin terminal

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

I am new to Android NDK and i am trying to run hello world app on emulator/ android device(v4.0).

I am getting following error while executing `ndk-build` command

```
$ ndk-build
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
/bin/sh: /cygdrive/e/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android                                                                                                                -4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc: cannot execute binar                                                                                                                y file
/cygdrive/e/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r10/build/core/build-binary.mk:447: recipe fo                                                                                                                r target 'obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/hello-jni/hello-jni.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] Error 126
```

Can any one help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use cygwin terminal.

```
How to:
1. run cmd.exe
2. cd xxx\hello-jni
3. ndk-build
4. done
```

Comment: Thanks Yushulx, but its not getting run and giving error "the system cannot find tha path specified"

Comment: Have you added your ndk path to "environments variables->system variables->path" ?

Comment: Is your platform 32-bit or 64-bit? Check whether you are using the right NDK package.

Comment: I'll just add a note that cygwin support in the NDK is pretty broken as paths aren't mangled/unmangled consistently so I would strongly advise following yushuix's advice and using a plain command prompt.